# Como Mantener Sesion al reiniciar servicios con Tomcat 9 y Genexus 17/18

Tags: java, mysql, genexus, tomcat, sesiones

Mi consulta es la siguiente, estoy desarrollando un Wizard en Genexus 17 U11 (Java) y WorkWithPlus para un proceso manual en el Sistema, pero en la mitad del mismo, debemos reiniciar los servicios (Tomcat y MySql) para liberar recursos del servidor y sacar de sesion a todos los usuarios que no participen de dicho proceso. Pero obviamente, tambien saca de sesion al encargado del proceso, cortando asi, el Wizard teniendo que acceder manualmente al paso en el que se quedó.

¿Hay una manera de mantener sesion a un usuario en especifico?

Desde ya, muchas gracias! Saludos!